# How to disable minimize and maximize buttons of windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Screenshot]

I want to disable Minimize and Maximize buttons of child form. There should be only close button.

Note : I disable Maximize and minimize buttons from property window. But I didn't work.

Comment: Try use FormBorderStyle=FixedToolWindow

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var f = new Form();
f.MinimizeBox = false;
f.MaximizeBox = false;
f.Show();
```

Comment: Or simply this.MinimizeBox = false and this.MaximizeBox = false in the constructor of the form.

Comment: @JohnSaps form does not have constructor with parameters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 . Maybe you mean object initializer? So, its the same.